# How to make this letter in LaTeX?

Tags: amsmath

[image]

What is this letter called? How to generate it in LaTeX?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! It remainds me on `\vartheta`: `\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
$\vartheta_{b}$
\end{document}`

Comment: See also: [How to look up a symbol or identify a letter from a math alphabet or other character?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14/134144)

Comment: @Zarko thank you <3